# Editing HTML source code with Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser, html, notepad

In Internet Explorer I can open a local .html file and edit it by selecting "Source" in the "View" menu," make a quick change, and then "Refresh" (reload) the web page.

How can I do that with Google Chrome?

Can I have the .html file open in Windows Notepad?  (I like notepad because it's really fast.)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`Ctrl+Shift+I or F12` -> Elements, It should show your source. Right click on any element and click `Edit as HTML`

**Edit:**

There are some extensions that look like what you want: https://chrome.google.com/extensions/search?itemlang=&q=editor

`ChromeEditor` & `Live WebSite Editor` look promising.

**Added by barlop**
I see that (after ctrl-shift-I / F12), right clicking the `<HTML..> or </HTML>` tag  and clicking "edit as html". allows me to edit anywhere within it. Choosing the opening tag means the popup for editing just covers all the html source that's there - which is very neat in terms of space when editing. Choosing the closing tag might be useful as the popup then appears under the html so you see a before/after.  Or better, as benjamin says, F2 to edit, ctrl-enter to commit.

Comment: sometimes I right click and it says edit html, sometimes edit as text. sometimes it refreshes automatically, sometimes it doesn't

Comment: try clicking exactly on the tag name for instance `<body>`

Comment: that helps.. I see I can it makes a difference whether I right click the tag or within them.. But once I left click outside them, the pages changes, then I refresh the page, and changes are gone. How do I save? And how would I add another tag/element? like add <p>sdf</p> to the html?

Comment: This is debugging tool. It is not editing tool. For creating pages use something like Aptana, Netbeans or other more suitable IDE. With tag completion, reference, javascript completion etc. . This is much more productive way to create web pages. If you insisting on using Chrome Developer Tools as your html editor there is `copy as html` context menu option. So you can paste it back to your main text editor of choice or other tool.

Comment: I don't insist on using chrome debugging tools. It was just your idea, and may not such a good solution to this.  Cheers for the IDE tips though and the note on what that chrome developer tool is for. Suppose my IDE is whatever it is. And i've got an html file I wrote locally. How can I from chrome, get that file opened up in my IDE? I guess that's something there should be a plugin for. Though I don't know of one

Comment: With IDE (for instance http://aptana.com/) it is actually the other way around. What I mean is, that from IDE you specify which browser  displays your code. On top of that IDE usually is starting its own local development web server. Not getting to much into details, the whole workflow of creating web pages is smoothen.

Comment: I'll give you an example of where what i'm wanting to do is more efficient. Suppose I don't need an IDE. The HTML file is so small and so simple, that I can edit it in notepad as easily as an IDE can. I don't need to go through the process of opening notepad and specifying or browsing to the file. That'd just be done with one or two clicks. And the file is open in notepad. I only need one or two changes, that I can do very efficiently in just notepad, for reasons mentioned. And I don't even need notepad to remain open, cluttering my taskbar. I can close it. refresh, not even a new tab needed

Comment: It's not for what one might call "web development". No big project, no flashy stuff.  It's quickly changing an HTML file that I am viewing locally in my browser. That is a very efficient way of doing it. Internet Explorer has been able to do it for ages(perhaps even since its birth).. I would like it if chrome could.

Comment: Closest to what you are talking about that I am aware of, is Firebug addon in Firefox. Among many various javascript/css/dom debugging tools it gives you in context menu on a page `Open with Editor` option. You can add several editors. Of course you can configure it to use Notepad.

Comment: I see that right clicking the <HTML/ tag and clicking edit

Comment: it's a little faster using F2 to edit and Ctrl+Enter to commit

Comment: To casualcoder and @Benjamin  Even when I do ctrl-ENTER, I notice that if I reload the page the change isn't saved. And i'm talking about for a local page , so there should be a way to save though I don't see it

Comment: F2 and F2 again does the same job as Ctrl+Enter.

Answer (score 24):

1. open DevTools.
2. open Elements panel.
3. select html or body or another element you want.
4. open console by Esc.
5. write $0.contentEditable = true

now you can edit text on the page and move images but it is not that you really want :)

Comment: not really what I want, but that is a very amusing feature!

Comment: Am I right that this is on by default in current Chrome versions? I mean, I already can edit in the Elements tab.

Comment: I just gave you +100 using this feature.

Comment: Really amazing feature

Comment: @Benjamin  Are you serious about the +100 (i.e. did you give him extra votes in your local copy obviously not going to have an effect on the site itself but still), that would be interesting.. How did you do that? or were you making a very bad and misleading joke?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this InlineEditor to edit and save static html in browser pages here is the [demo](http://xreader.github.com/inplaceeditor/demo.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to edit the file as html source (and not individual elements) you can do the following:

1. select 'Sources' tab on the left side
2. right click in the 'Sources' pane and select 'Add folder to workspace' and add folder with source HTML file
3. right click the html file you want to edit and select 'map to network resource'

Comment: This is the correct way to develop in browser